# matplotlib matshow: How to change each row height based on a scaling vector?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the standard matshow example:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
dim = (12,12)
aa = zeros(dim)
for i in range(min(dim)):
    aa[i,i] = i
matshow(aa)
show()
```

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/_images/matshow_00.png))</sub>

How can I control each row's height?

In my case the row indices (i.e countries) could be represented by non-linear spacing (such as GDP) to signify magnitude and I would like to represent that by altering the row height from a scaling vector. (i.e. If there are 12 rows then with the uniform distribution each row would have a row height of 1/12 represented by [0.083, 0.083, ...., 0.083] then uneven row heights could be set by any vector that sums to 1)

Comment: Do you want a bar chart? Could you supply an example image to show what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pcolormesh (or pcolor) to create an array made of polygons, these can have any shape you want. I think normal array plotting like matshow or imshow will always have a constant size along an axis.

```
n = 6

# generate some data
gdp = np.array(np.random.randint(10,500,n))
countries = np.array(['Country%i' % (i+1) for i in range(n)])
matr = np.random.randint(0,10,(n,n))

# get the x and y arrays
y = np.insert(gdp.cumsum(),0,0)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n+1),y)

# plot the matrix
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

axs.pcolormesh(xx,yy,matr.T, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, edgecolors='k')

axs.set_ylim(y.min(),y.max())

# set the yticks + labels
axs.set_yticks(y[1:] - np.diff(y) / 2)
axs.set_yticklabels(countries)

#set xticks + labels
axs.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
axs.set_xticks(np.arange(n)+0.5)
axs.set_xticklabels(np.arange(n))
```

The height is scaled according to:

```
print countries
['Country1' 'Country2' 'Country3' 'Country4' 'Country5' 'Country6']

print gdp
[421 143 134 388 164 420]
```

[image]

Comment: excellent ... this is exactly what I am trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: Only one minor edit. 'X' should be 'countries' in the above example.

Comment: Your right thanks, dont know how that happened. I replaced `len(X)` with simply `n` in this case, `len(countries)` would also work.

Comment: This is a great method for incorporating another dimension while visualizing data.